# vi: use key bindings (mappings) in different editor modes

Tags: vim, vi

I would like to define a vi key binding C-c that would copy the word under the cursor. The current version is:

```
nmap <C-c> <ESC>yaw<CR>
```

The leading ESC allows to use it from either insert or normal mode, but has the undesirable side effect of always landing the editor in normal mode after use. Is there a way to do something to the effect of

```
nmap <C-c> if(editor.mode == NORMAL) yaw<CR> else <C-o>yaw<CR>
```

That will land the user in the same mode she started in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- what you are creating is not macro, it is a mapping in vim.
- the `<CR>` at the end of your `rhs` is not necessary

vim supports mappings on different modes, you can create to mappings:

```
nnoremap <C-c> ....  "only for normal mode
inoremap <C-c> ....  "only for insert mode
```

Vim do have the option you meant, the `<expr>` mapping. It gets the `rhs` keys by evaluating your expression. But it won't work with your `nmap <expr> ...` Because, if you were in `insert` mode, the mapping will not be applied, due to the `nmap`.

I suggest you reading `:h map-expr` and `:map` to understand the relation between `:map` and modes.